# Looping prompt on onclick

Tags: javascript, for-loop, prompt

So I have a php file that loops contents from MySQL into different divs. and every div has an id of `"name".$j++`. I've put a button in the loop that whenever it's clicked a prompt display woulds show. Every button also has an id of `"button".$i++.` I want the input in the prompt box to be displayed at the end of the div. (different for each div.)

with my current code I can only show one input at the end of each div. When I try to add a second one to div1 it goes automatically to div2 and so on...

**JS**

```
var n = (<?php echo $i; ?>);
for(var i=0; i<=n; i++){
for(var j=0; j<=n; j++){


document.getElementById("button"+i).onclick = function() {
    var money;
    money = prompt("Write something here:");
    if(money === null){
        return;
    }else{
        $("<p> " + money + "</p>").appendTo("#div"+ j++);
    }
}
}}
```

picture [image]

Comment: I'm confused why you have a loop in a loop. Let's say n is 10. That means you'll loop through your onclick code 100 times, overwriting each one 10 times.

Comment: Because my divs (in the php) are looped to always have +1 and my button too, so i figured that in my js i should loop the button to always get +1 and the div to get plus one but since div != button they should have different variables. Otherwise i can only open prompt through one button only. i can't think of any other way to do this...

Comment: I think seeing your desired HTML output would be helpful.

Comment: I think the MySQL loop is irrelevant to the issue at hand, and I think a closure is needed to maintain the desired div index when the onclick is fired.

Comment: Are you saying that I should delete the  $i++ and $j++ from the end of the div ids in the php loop, or i should not care about them? sorry I'm a little confused now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the MySQL loop is irrelevant to the problem at hand, and the value of the variable `j` in `appendTo("#div"+ j++)` is scoped outside the loop, so is not what you expect by the time the onclick function is fired.

So, a single loop is used to set the onclick event for each div/button group, and the `bind` function method is used to lock the current scope into the anonymous function getting passed to the onclick event handler (therefore locking in the current value of `j`), and passing `j` (in the form of `jj` for clarity) to that function.

```
for(var j=1; j<=n; j++){
  document.getElementById("button"+j).onclick = function(jj) {
    var money;
    money = prompt("Write something here:");
    if(money === null){
        return;
    }else{
        $("<p> " + money + "</p>").appendTo("#div"+ jj++);
    }
  }.bind(this, j);
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/xc0La8ov/